# Facebook comments plugin not showing up (while the codes are present)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

The blank area on the lower right side is where facebook comments should be but its not showing. All the correct codes are there. Here is the url:

http://dev16.thinqcloud.com/videos/bb4a0c4313ad9f6e3dacdc2236552ac2

if anyone can help me out, would be very appreciated!

Comment: I'm able to see the comments plugin just fine. You have 0 comments, but it's definitely there. What's the issue you're having?

Comment: hmm.. I deleted the photo on that link I posted , it shouldn't show up at all.

Comment: The issue is for me the comment plugin isn't showing up at all, any browser, desktop or mobile devices. Here is an active url, can you comment on it I want to see if its doing it canonically thanks! http://dev16.thinqcloud.com/videos/ee16176f2bce99e718aba2d2761c9e07

Comment: I must be going blind, two other people said they see the comments plugin as well